# How to access global constant in unit tests with Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, rxjs, jestjs

I want to mock a global variable and test if it has been called in my function. In my file, I define a global variable "remote" which instanciates a Subject (RxJS library). I just want to test if the next function of Subject has been called with the right parameter "name". However, I can't access the global variable remote in my test file. I tried to mock it in my setup file, but doesn't work.

How can I do that ?

```
const remote = new Subject();
const analytics = {
  click: (name) => {
    if (name) {
      remote.next(name);
    }
  }
}
module.exports = analytics;
```

Thanks !

Comment: I guess you are using webpack, and `remote` is not a global variable

Comment: Hey @Zen thanks for the answer. Yes Im using webpack. Jest is telling me that it doesn't know the property "next" of new Subject (if you know a bit about observables, next is a classic method of Subject's class). Any idea about how I can do to make Jest know about "remote" variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question. When you use webpack, your individual file is wrapped into different function call. Check out this [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper).
  The best part of this question is that it shows the necessity of IOC/DI if you want your code to be testable. Instead of defining `remote` in your local module, you can export an `Analytics` class and then inject `remote` to its constructor.

```
// Analytics.js
export default class Analytics{
  constructor(remote) {
    this.remote = remote
  }

  click(name) {
    if (name) {
      this.remote.next(name)
    }
  }
}

main.js
import Analytics from './Analytics'

const remote = new Subject()
const analytics = new Analytics(remote)
analysis.click('foo')
```

It would be tedious to inject dependencies to all components/services. Angular has [an decent doc](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) on why/how to simplify it. Hope this is helpful!

// Update
  You can use window to define global constant and access it in tests by using `window.remote`

```
const remote = new Subject()
window.remote = remote
```

When you want to mock remote, remember to modify its properties rather than the reference to it.

```
// test.js
beforeEach(() => {
    // wrong !!!
    window.remote = {
        next(name) { assert(name) }
    }

    // right
    window.remote.next = name => assert(name)
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The doc NodeJS is pretty useful. I agree that this solution would be the best one; however Im working with legacy code I can't refactore ... Any idea how I could test it anyway ?

Comment: Thanks @Zen, Im gonna check it out!